# Relative module paths when loading submodule

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, module

Say that I am loading a submodule using `python -m ...`. This module is part of a package. How can I load, using relative paths (e.g., `import ..foo.bar`) a module somewhere else in the package tree, such as a parent module? Perhaps this can be achieved by setting `__package__` and/or `__name__` appropriately in various files?

Comment: `PYTHONPATH=$(realpath ..) python -m foo.bar`?

Comment: @Marat To be clear, the solution should be purely Pythonic, and I don't strictly have control over how the submodule is loaded.

Comment: Can you give more details then? `python -m` kind of implies it is called from shell/script

Comment: That may have been misleading, but it was just meant to make it easy to understand. In the real case it is another program loading my module in a way I can’t externally control, and then running a certain function within it.

Comment: what is the working dir when the program is running and how does it discover the main package?

Comment: It is some dirt containing a symlink to the submodule file.

Comment: something like `sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__name__)), '..'))` should work. If you list an example folder strucutre, I'll add more specific example

Comment: @Marat That would work yes, but I was hoping for a solution that takes advantage of the fact this submodule exists within a package, and the relative path module importing syntax...

Comment: unfortunately, no. Relative import will follow symlink, realpath has to be involved

Comment: Hmm? You mean they do *not* follow symlinks?

Comment: Say, there is a symlink `/home/user1/programs/bar => /usr/lib/python/site-packages/foo/bar`. An executable in `/home/user1/programs` imports `bar`. For `bar`, `..` points to `/home/user1/programs`, not `/usr/lib/python/site-packages/foo` - making relative imports impossible

Comment: @Marat Are you sure? I was told that Python relative imports correspond to the package structure, not filesystem paths.

Comment: yes, I'm pretty sure about that. Also, in my comment `sys.path.append...` above I meant to use `__file__`, not `__name__`

Comment: Okay, cheers. What about in the case where I'm not using a symlink, and the file being loaded is the submodule file itself?